# How to replace content within an Iframe

Tags: iframe, replace

I have an Iframe on this page and would like to change the text that comes up in the Iframe. Wondering if this is possible.
Aloha,
Greg

Comment: Here's the page: http://hawaiiproducts.net/west-maui-resorts/aina-nalu.html

Comment: using jQuery you can do something like `$('#myiframeid').empty().load(myiframeUrl);`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text in the iframe if you can pass in URL variables to the iframe. That's probably the easiest way if you can access it.

If you can't edit the code in the iframe, can you please give more details about the setup?

Comment: Thanks. Here's the code: <div style="margin:-78px 0 0 -23px;">
<iframe src="http://secure.instantsoftwareonline.com/stayusa/default.aspx?coid=1338" width="1018" height="450" frameborder="0">  
</iframe> 
</div>

Comment: I want to replace a phone number that comes up and other text if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As defined by [HTML5 iframe Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#security-nav), there are four casess under which you you can access the contents of an iFrame.

> A [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) A is allowed to navigate a second [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context)
>   B if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - Either the [origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/origin-0.html#origin) of the [active document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#active-document) of A is the same as the
>     [origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/origin-0.html#origin) of the [active document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#active-document) of B, or
> - The browsing context A is a nested browsing context with a
>     top-level    browsing context, and its top-level browsing context is
>     B, or
> - The browsing context B is an auxiliary browsing context and A is
>     allowed to navigate B's opener browsing context, or
> - The browsing context B is not a top-level browsing context, but
>     there    exists an ancestor browsing context of B whose active
>     document has    the same [origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/origin-0.html#origin) as the [active document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#active-document) of A (possibly
>     in fact being A    itself).

Basically it boils down to the fact that unless the iframe your trying to access is not under the same domain as the parent page, then you wont be able to access it.

Comment: How about specifying part of the information from the Iframe URL be placed and not the whole page? I would like to pull just the Form part and not the other information. http://secure.instantsoftwareonline.com/stayusa/default.aspx?coid=1338

Comment: You can use a server side language to load the url and get the form, but you wont be able to post the data back to the form unless original page allows cross domain posting.

Comment: Where do I find the server side language to implement?

Comment: By server side language I mean either PHP, asp.net etc